# .bin file upload to web server using cURL is not working

Tags: php, html, http, curl, server

I need to upload a file to a web server using cURL. The web app looks like this:

[Click here to view a screen capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LyFf.png)
This is part of the HTML code (the complete code is 300 lines, it's a very simple web app on an embedded system to run 3D printers called Smoothieboard):

```html
<h2> Upload File </h2>
<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" onchange="upload();">

<h3>Uploading file(s)</h3>
<output id="list"></output>
<div id="progress"></div>
<div id="uploadresult"></div>
<script>
  document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
</script>
```

When the user clicks the "browse" button, a window pops up to browse the file system and pick a file. My file is called "firmware.bin". Upon selecting the file, the upload begins immediately (there is no "upload" button, the file's transfer is done right after picking it). I need to automate this task using cURL. I'm currently doing the following:

```
curl -i -F files[]=@/home/pi/P18/firmware.bin http://192.168.3.222/upload
```

The output is:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Server: uIP/1.0
Connection: close
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Type: text/plain

OK
```

However, it doesn't seem to be working. I can access the server through other means and I can assure you that the usual human-friendly upload procedure works, but what I'm doing with cURL doesn't. Something DOES seem to be going on, since the OK message takes a few seconds to pop up, which also happens in the web app. The file seems to be transfered, but I feel that I need to do something more to complete the process.

Something that caught my attention is that, whether I type files[] or potatoes[], the same thing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Without the `upload()` function, it's hard to reproduce the problem but what you can do is just extracting the `curl` request with Chrome development console :

In Network Tab, check "Preserve logs", reload the page, upload the file, right click on request / Copy / Copy as cURL :

[image]